# Automatically create a calendar document using Google Drive and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible to use Google Apps Script to 'automatically' create a calendar document in Google Drive with the following document features.

- Traditional calendar table
- Accurate month and year heading
- Dates accurately placed in the correct day columns

[See example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XN_HpylAqnKVWu9UhkuFtwgvFSOuJb6c4y9E8xuLc5A/edit?usp=sharing)

I know Google Apps Script can automatically create documents and add content. I'm just not sure it can "automatically" and "accurately" place dates in the correct locations. I don't want to start down the path if the goal I seek isn't an option.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 14 times. Questions asking if something is possible to save time on doing a task like writing a script are not a good fit for Web Applications. Instead try the Google Apps Script official community or the Google Apps Script chatroom on Stack Overflow. The link is on the Google Apps Script tag on Stack Overflow. You might also try to find Google Apps Script experts in other chatrooms. Checkout the [tour] and [ask].